# 240v pool timer with 120v outlet, proper usage?

Tags: pool, timer

[image]My pool cleaner timer which is 240v has a outlet added that looks like a 120v.

Can I use the outlet to plug in a 120v light or must it be a 240v?

(*looks like a standard 120v outlet one finds in a house*).

Comment: Does the pool cleaner timer get a white neutral wire as well as the two hots?  (neutral is not ground).  Does the plug really look the same? (there are 240V sockets that are dead ringers for household sockets, but the slots are moved somewhat).

Comment: the pool timer yes b ut only one white and one black attached to the outlet.  I just added a picture of the plugs

Comment: @GregHonore -- can you post photos of the wiring feed coming into the pool timer?

Comment: How about at least putting a meter on it and measuring the voltage?   And, yes, agreed with harp, if 4 wire feed (2 hots, neutral and ground) it's probably just fine. If 3 wire feed, not really good.

Answer (score 1):

That is a 120v 15 amp receptacle. I hope you have a neutral feed to the pool or a transformer that is creating the 120v.

If this has been installed in the last 20 years, it should have a proper neutral and should be safe to use.

If it is an older system that had an added 120v circuit, then there may be some safety risks because the neutral for the light might be going back on the ground for the pool.

When skin is wet, the resistance of the skin is reduced and shocks affect us at lower voltages, this combined with muscle convulsions can cause drowning at low levels, so I always like to know the system prior to saying it is safe.

If your pool has a 4 wire feed and everything is properly wired and grounded, then it should be fine to plug in to that receptacle with a 120v device.